# Sentry - JavaScript Projects and Source Maps

Tags: error-logging, uglifyjs, source-maps, sentry

i have some questions about the Sentry handling of minified JavaScript code. My Projects have around ~3 MB of regular JavaScript, in production its reduced to 200 - 400kb.

How does it work if Sentry is implemented plus JavaScript Sourcemaps. If an error appears, will the client load the sourcemap (400 kb + the unminified version 3 mb) itself and process to find correct line ? This would be bad, since a lot of my projects target  mobile devices. Or will the Sentry Server access the sourcemap from the server and parse the correct Error?

Thanks for any knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sentry server will process the sourcemaps remotely as part of its pipeline. It looks for them based on the standard headers or annotations when it fetches the source itself, and will then fetch them automatically. In case of the files being unavailable publicly, there is also an API to send the files to the Sentry server using "releases".

Comment: So all i have to do is, make sourcemap, minified and original version public plus link the sourcemap in the minified version in order to get it to work?

Comment: Thats correct. Here is a gist of the releases API as well, which is the preferred method: https://gist.github.com/dcramer/619d53dabfbc2ed008a1